# How do I give every player a part that follows them?

Tags: lua, roblox, luau

I am trying to give every player another set of arms. The original "arm part" will be cloned for a player and it will follow them.

This is what I have so far:

```
    local model = game.Workspace.Viewmodel 
    model.Parent = game.Players.ImSpacemanRB
    model.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame = model.Parent:FindFirstChildWhichIsA("Humanoid").RootPart.CFrame
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use AlignPositions and AlignOrientations, set `Attachment0` of both to an attachment in "arm model"'s primarypart (every part in model should be welded to primarypart) and set `Attachment1` to an attachment in player's character's primarypart, i use them in pet systems ant it works pretty well!
Also for more details, read these docs:

[AlignPosition](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/AlignPosition)

[AlignOrientation](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/AlignOrientation)